# WebBrowser drag and drop an image with a link to WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, webbrowser-control

In my WPF application I have a WebBrowser control and a drag and drop area (a Border). I implemented some of the logic to handle the drag and drop including this:

```
private void DragAndDropArea_OnDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    var data = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text);
}
```

When I drag and drop the following elements form WebBrowser control to the Border it's ok:

- selected text - I get the text
- a link - I get the URL
- an image - I get it's url

But I can't figure out how to handle an image which is also a link. The **data** contains the url to the page the image's link points to, while I want the url to the image itself. How can I get it?

PS

By the "image with a link" i mean

```
<a href="..."><img src="..."/></a>
```

Comment: Not my area, but can't you use the `WebClient` class? (Something along this area: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe.aspx).

Comment: @Tico Not yet. I need the url of this image to download it later with WebClient or something else. Instead I get the url to another web page.

Comment: Interesting, can you send an example of a real case?

Comment: @Tico For example if I drag and drop StackOverflow logo I get "http://stackoverflow.com/".

Comment: Can you show your on Drag and how you set the data of the Drag item?

Comment: Weird, I'll help you find something.

Comment: @LeoLorenzoLuis I didn't implement Drag. WebBrowser already implements it.

Comment: I think one option could be to use `DataFormats.Html` and parse the `Html`

Comment: Where is this Image coming from? Is it outside the WebBrowser or within the WebBrowser?

Comment: @TI But it returns the whole html code of the page, how can I get the right image?

Comment: @LeoLorenzoLuis In my WebBrowser control I navigate to http://stackoverflow.com/ and than drag the logo from it.

Comment: I haven't tested or read back but if its possible you might want to override/hook up to the Drag event and see if you can manipulate the data that will be drop there.